# Unable to find installed SDK from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

**Facing issue to find installed SDK Android APIs :**

I have installed SDK - Android API's in eclipse successfully. 
Even I have seen in Windows>Preference> Android, it was showing my all installed APIs here.

Later I have changed SDK location from Windows>Preference>Android, due to change of location it was not showing the installed API's there.

I am not able find now the installed Android APIs location in my system. 
After changing the SDK location, it is again asking me to install SDK Android APIs.

I don't want to install those APIs again, my harddisk is already full. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Are you sure you've set the correct SDK location? If so, restart eclipse/windows and check again.

Comment: When I have installed SDK, it was in location C:\Users\user\.... I have checked that location too, now not able to find it. Even restarted eclipse 2-3 times, not showing that installed APIs in windows preference

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse we have option to view already install software.
Go to Help>Install Software> There will be link for "already installed". You will get your installed tools details.